# Elastic collision with circles

Tags: java, math, physics, game-physics

I am making an air hockey game where the user can control a mallet using the mouse and the computer can control another mallet. I want to handle a collision between the puck and the mallet so the puck can change direction and speed (or velocity) based on the speed and angle of the mallet when they collided without changing the speed of the mallet. I prefer a solution that is not necessarily 100% correct in physics because I don't want to change the whole game but I want it to work and make sense. I am making this is Java but I don't mind an answer in pseudo-code or another language so that others can benefit from this post. Here is my code for the Update method in my game:

```
    public void update(long tP) {
    if (!getPause() && getGameMode()!="menu") {
        player.update(player.getDistanceX(), player.getDistanceY(), getFps());
        computer.update(puck.getX(), puck.getY());
        puck.update();
        if (puck.circleCollide(player)||puck.circleCollide(computer)) {
            puck.setSpeedX((int)(-5*getScaleFactor()));

        }

        if (puck.rectCollide(myGoal) || puck.rectCollide(computerGoal)) {
            String scorer = puck.rectCollide(myGoal) ? "Computer" : "Player";
            puck.setSpeedX(0);
            puck.setSpeedY(0);
            puck.setX(s.getWidth()/2);
            puck.setY(s.getHeight()/2);
            if (scorer=="Computer") {
                computer.addGoal();
            } else if (scorer=="Player") {
                player.addGoal();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment the puck just moves to the left at a certain speed. This is where I want to make it do something else. All the other posts assume that both the circles can move after colliding and do not take into account the angle of collision.

Comment: Note: you probably don't want to compare a `String` with `!=`. Do `!getGameMode().equals("menu")`

Comment: Did you make the the classes of `puck`, `player`, and `computer`? If so, their code may be useful.

Comment: True, I should have thought about that. To not compare references but value.

Comment: @ricky3350 Yes, they all extend the class circle so I can include that code.  Player is from class mallet and computer is from compmallet which extends mallet. Some of the methods are overridden.

Comment: The puck class just has the collision detection methods and the circle class has the basic things that would be found in a sprite class such as getter and setter methods for positions and speeds.

Comment: You could potentially get velocity vector of the mallet on collision and apply that to the puck or am I missing something?

Comment: What if the mallet is not moving and the puck collides with it?

Comment: Depending on whether mallet is movable you can take the velocity of puck on collision and negate at an angle (you can calculate angle from velocity). If mallet can be moved by puck, half the velocity and apply to mallet

Comment: The mallet is moveable but only by the player or artificial intelligence because it is simulating a person holding it in real life. How do you calculate angle from velocity?

Comment: atan2(velocity.y / velocity.x) gives angle in rad. Convert to degrees and you get an angle at which it was moving

Comment: So if I do that then all that is left is to calculate the angle of bounce and get the new velocities from that?

Comment: How would I work out the angle that it bounces? If it is head on and moving at 90 degrees then it would bounce straight back but if it was a slight glance then it would only change angle slightly.

Comment: well the above angle is against vector 1, 0 aka x-axis. If you want an angle between 2 velocity vectors you can obtain it using dot product. Here's a tutorial http://www.vitutor.com/geometry/vec/angle_vectors.html

Comment: Would this work with a velocity vector of value zero (aka if one of the circles is not moving)? This looks interesting but I am not sure how to implement it in my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81743/discussion-between-almasb-and-sayed-hajaj).

Comment: I'm a bit stumped at the example to be honest, I do not do how 3.5 comes from the dot product from 3 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want is not an *elastic collision* in the physical sense, since the paddle is controlled by the player and therefore the paddle + puck system is not closed (that is, the total momentum and energy are *not* constant). Instead, I think you're looking to model the force of the paddle on the puck in a collision so that you can update the velocity of the puck accordingly.

When two circles collide the force of each on the other is directed *along the line connecting their centers*. So in your case the force of the paddle on the puck is in the direction of the vector difference between the center of the paddle (black) to the center of the puck (blue):

[image: direction of force of the paddle (black) on puck (blue)]

To implement this in your update, you can do something like

```
if (puck.circleCollide(player)) {
    double dx, dy, norm, fx, fy;

    dx = puck.getX() - player.getX(); // distance between centers in x
    dy = puck.getY() - player.getY(); // distance between centers in y

    // define unit-length vector (fx, fy) in direction of the force
    dist = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy); // norm of (dx, dy)
    fx = dx/dist;
    fy = dy/dist;

    // may need to cast arguments to int, depending on your interface...
    puck.setSpeedX(puck.getSpeedX() + fmag(dist)*fx);
    puck.setSpeedY(puck.getSpeedY() + fmag(dist)*fy);
}
```

(and similarly for the computer player's paddle).

Now, how to decide the magnitude of the force (the function `fmag(dist)` in the example)? One simple way is to just make it a constant (independent of `dist`), for example:

```
double fmag(double dist) { return 10.0; }
```

(Of course this is equivalent to replacing `fmag(dist)` by `10` in the example). This means that whenever the paddle and puck overlap, the puck will accelerate away from the center of the paddle at a constant rate. This isn't the most physically realistic method but is the simplest to implement.

A more realistic method is to make the magnitude of the force proportional to the amount of overlap between the paddle and the puck, for example

```
double fmag(double dist) { return 10.0*((rPaddle + rPuck) - dist); }
```

where `rPaddle` and `rPuck` are the radii of the paddle and the puck respectively. This is the physics you would get if the paddle and puck behaved as perfect springs, with spring constant equal to 10 in the example.

You can play with the functional form of `fmag(dist)` and the constant value to get the behavior you're happy with.

Comment: This sounds good and I might test it but the problem is that it doesn't take in enough factors and is therefore not precise enough. What I mean is that what I want is the user to be able to control where the puck will move and at which angle based on not only the magnitude of the mallet and puck's velocities but also the angle they collide. For example-if it was a head on collision there should be a different response to a glancing collision with the same velocities. However, what is good about this is that there will be a response even if one of the circles is not moving.